# Error when deploying React application to GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github, deployment, web-deployment

[Error Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewo9c.png)

First time attempting to deploy a site, here is what I have tried.

Run the react application locally to make sure its working.

Followed this tutorial:
https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f

Running the command "npm run deploy" at the last step gives me the above error message and I can't find any solution.

Comment: Don't use images when you can copy-paste the actual text of an error message. (See [ask].)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.